# How do I know the Math version used by a mathml document?

Tags: mathml

I was at a tutorial site. It is supposed to teach Math ML 3. I see in examples, the top line is

```
<math xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

I think Given MathML came out in 2014. The use of folder "1998" makes me ask this question. Or is it just a misleading folder name?
How do I know the Math version used by a mathml document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a misleading folder name ... my browser didn't seem to care what I put for the `xmlns`. **Firefox** was fine with just using `<math>` without the other stuff.